# Accessing hardware or memory from C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible from C# calling a Win32 API or a generic DLL that do
access directly to hardware or memory?

I read about interoperability, unsafe e unmanaged DLL...

For example if I write a DLL in C that bitmask some bit to
a device is after possible from C# call that DLL?

In the same way if I write a DLL in C that allocate a chunk of raw
memory, provide read and write functions, can I call from C#
that DLL to read or write that chunk of memory?

Comment: This is how a lot of the .NET Framework is implement. Eventually it has to call into the native OS.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, it is possible to call native Windows dlls from C#; the technique, on which tutorials and definitions can be found [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/), is called 'platform invoke'. From a user's perspective, method signatures and types used in the respective dll have to be redefined in C# - then, the method signatures have to be equipped with a suitable `DllImport` attribute, which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Within the referenced dll, all kinds of desired 'native' things can be performed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible from C# calling a Win32 API or a generic DLL that do access directly to hardware or memory?

No. Whilst you can call the Win32 API from C#, there no Win32 APIs that provide direct access to memory or hardware. Only device drivers are able to access memory or hardware directly.

Your C# code, and indeed unmanaged Win32 code, executes in **user mode**. User mode code cannot directly access memory or hardware. To do that, the code must execute in **kernel mode**, and that requires a device driver.

Device drivers cannot be implemented in C#. Typically device drivers are implemented in C. You could implement a device driver to do whatever you need to do, and communicate with it from C# by calling `DeviceIoControl`.

Comment: But if I develop a device driver in C and create a DLL to manage it can I use that DLL from C# via interop and unsafe code like Codor says into his answer?